# Using double pointer in a stack program in reference to array index location

Tags: c

I have a stack program I completed using single pointers. Now I have to use double pointers of type `double` to reference the index to an element in an array of type double. I made a random number generator and I am trying to satisfy these 4 conditions.

- The stack is going to be in the form of an array of doubles.
- The third argument to push() and the second argument to pop() are going to be in the form of
  `double **top`, i.e. a pointer to pointer which stores the address of the current top element on the stack. Hint: in these functions, modify *top as the stack is updated.
- A global integer variable myerror is created for you. Its value could be STACK_FULL, STACK_EMPTY, and NORMAL. Use this variable in your push() and pop() functions to inform the main() function the status of the operations.
- Test your functions in main(). See details in the skeleton code stack.c.

I am lost on how to pass double pointer to the push function. That is type double.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

#define STACK_SIZE  10

#define STACK_FULL      -2
#define STACK_EMPTY     -1
#define NORMAL          0

int myerror = NORMAL;

void push(double [],    // input/ouput - the stack
          double,   // input - data being pushed onto the stack
          double **,    // input/output - pointer to pointer to the top of stack
          int);     // constant - maximum capacity of stack

double          // output - data being popped out from the stack
pop(double [],  // input/output - the stack
    double **); // input/output - pointer to pointer to top of stack

void push(double stack[], double item, double **top, int max_size)
{
    if(**top==(max_size-1))
    {
        printf("Stack is Full\n");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
    }
    return;

}

double pop(double stack[],
           double **top){     
}

int main(){
    double s[STACK_SIZE];
    double *s_top = NULL;
    int max_size=STACK_SIZE;
    double **top;
    top=&s_top;

    srand(time(NULL));

    int i;
    double randNum=0.0;

    for(i=0; i<STACK_SIZE; i++)
    {
        randNum = 94.0*(rand()/(RAND_MAX + 1.0));
        randNum = randNum + 33.0;
        printf("\nRandom double : %f\n ",randNum);
        //      push(s, randNum, top, max_size);
    }
    printf("-----------\n");


    // Keep pushing doubles equivalent to chars randomly picked between '!'(33) and '~'(126)
    // to the stack until it is full.
    // Print each double before each pushing.

    // Keep popping out doubles from the stack until it is empty
    // Print each double after each popping.

    // Repeat above until the user says 'no'.      

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your use of the phrase "double pointer" is potentially confusing. The term is sometimes used to refer to a pointer to a pointer (`some_type **`), sometimes to refer to a pointer to `double` (`double*`). You seem to be using it to refer to both.

Comment: i saw that, what i mean is that it is a pointer of a pointer that is of type double

Comment: The correct terminology would be a pointer *to* pointer *to* `double`. A pointer can't be of type `double`; it can be of type `double*`, or `double**`, or ...

Answer (score 0):

When calling push, pass the address of the top-of-stack pointer. It looks like `s_top` is the pointer to the top-of-stack, so when calling `push` you'd use:

```
push(s,          /* the entire stack */
     randNum,    /* the number being added to the stack */
     &s_top,     /* pass the ADDRESS of the pointer which points to the top-of-stack */
     max_size);  /* the maximum size of the stack - could also just pass STACK_SIZE */
```

+1 on the question, as this is a good way to ask for help with a homework problem. You're not asking to have the whole problem solved, just asking for assistance with something that you don't understand.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: i see, on my machine, each double is 8 bytes, so in my push function i have an if else statement that check to see if it is full or not and in the NOT part i have this: stack[**top]=item; which throws an error saying array subscript is not an integer, dont know how to tie the double "top of stack" pointer to my array index. is that something im supposed to do ?

Comment: A pointer is not a subscript. If you're using `s_top` (declared as `double *`) as the pointer to the location into which you want to store something you should `*s_top = item;` - in other words, store the value of `item` into the location pointed to by `s_top`. You'd use the `double **top` (which is a pointer to the pointer to the top-of-stack) to change the top-of-stack pointer - as in `*top = &stack[n]` - in other words, store the address of the n-th element of stack into the `double *` pointed to by `top`. I hope this helps.

Comment: Looking at this again - in your example (`stack[**top] = item;`), the subscript you supplied as `**top` is a double - `**top` in this case means "the value of the double variable pointed to by the pointer which is pointed to by `top`".

Answer (score 0):

sample code

```
void push(double stack[], double item, double **top, int max_size){
    if(*top == stack + max_size){
        printf("Stack is Full\n");
        myerror = STACK_FULL;
        return;
    }
    **top = item;
    ++*top;
    myerror = NORMAL;
}

int main(){
    double s[STACK_SIZE];
    double *s_top = s;
    double randNum=0.0;

    srand(time(NULL));

    while(myerror != STACK_FULL){
        randNum = 94.0*(rand()/(RAND_MAX + 1.0));
        randNum = randNum + 33.0;
        printf("\nRandom double : %f\n ",randNum);
        push(s, randNum, &s_top, STACK_SIZE);
        //printf("%p, <%f>\n", (void*)s_top, s_top[-1]);
    }
    printf("-----------\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i see, i am trying to build the pop function from this,and i have [code]if(*top-stack>-1) { value=**top; --*top; myerror=NORMAL; [/code]this however skips the last item that was pushed and pops the second and then in the last element it pops 0.000 and says stack empty.